# Two different Rubygems installations!

Tags: rubygems

apologies if this is a bad stackoverflow question....I'm a ruby noob

On several OSX systems I have, I seem to have two different installations of rubygems because I can do

```
sudo gem install foobar
```

and then in my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'foobar'
```

and get

```
no such file to load — foobar
```

How do I solve this so I just have one installation of rubygems that all my code knows the location of?

Answer (score 1):

What you really need to do is investigate [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/), the Ruby Version Manager.  You can set up all sorts of independent Ruby installations with different gems, different versions of rails, and so forth, and control the paths.

For your specific issue, you need to make sure your Ruby search path goes where you think it does.

Comment: I have to admit I don't understand how my system got this way and at present have no use for multiple Rubygems installations.  How can I fix my search paths and have just one Rubygems installation?